# Extract code to an external function React native

Tags: react-native, jsx

I'm trying to move the switch out of the touchable element. I tried to write a function above of the constant but console says "const dosomenthing =>(){console.log("hi")}" is an object not a function.

'

```
const GP = 'https://www.something.es/'
const [ruta, setRuta] = useState(GP + "?app=1");
return (
    <>
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#1C8EBC' }} forceInset={{ top: 'always' }} >

            <WebView
                androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
                source={{ uri: ruta }}
                scalesPageToFit={true}
                onNavigationStateChange={(webViewState) => {setRuta(webViewState.url); console.log("algo")}}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
        <FlatList
            style={styles.list}
            horizontal
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            contentContainerStyle={{ paddingBottom: 10, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'space-around', backgroundColor: '#001E35', paddingTop: 10 }}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
            data={tracks}
            renderItem={({ item }) => {
                return (
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={function () {
                            
                            switch (item.name) {
                                case "inicio":
                                    tracks[0].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_inicio_activo_TS.png';
                                    tracks[1].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_tragaperras_TS.png';
                                    tracks[2].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_videobingo_TS.png';
                                    tracks[3].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_todobares_TS.png';
                                    setRuta(item.ruta)
                                    break;
                                case "tragaperras":
                                    tracks[0].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_inicio_TS.png';
                                    tracks[1].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_tragaperras_activo_TS.png';
                                    tracks[2].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_videobingo_TS.png';
                                    tracks[3].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_todobares_TS.png';
                                    setRuta(GP + item.ruta)
                                    break;
                                case "videobingo":
                                    tracks[0].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_inicio_TS.png';
                                    tracks[1].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_tragaperras_TS.png';
                                    tracks[2].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_videobingo_activo_TS.png';
                                    tracks[3].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_todobares_TS.png';
                                    setRuta(GP + item.ruta)
                                    break;
                                case "todobares":
                                    tracks[0].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_inicio_TS.png';
                                    tracks[1].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_tragaperras_TS.png';
                                    tracks[2].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_videobingo_TS.png';
                                    tracks[3].icon = '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_todobares_activo_TS.png';
                                    setRuta(GP + item.ruta)
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                         
                    }
                    }>
                        <Image
                            style={styles.image}
                            source={{ uri: GP + item.icon }}
                        />
                        <Text style={(GP + item.ruta == ruta || item.ruta == ruta ) && Platform.OS === 'ios' ? styles.titleColorPink : styles.titleIcon}>{item.name}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                );
            }}
        />
    </>
);
```

}

const tracks = [
{ name: 'inicio', ruta: 'https://www.something.es/?app=1', icon: '/img/layout/appIcons/.png' },
{ name: 'tragaperras', ruta: 'something?app=1', icon: '/img/layout/appIcons/.png' },
{ name: 'videobingo', ruta: '/something?app=1', icon: '/img/layout/appIcons/simbolo_videobingo_TS.png' },
{ name: 'todobares', ruta: '/something?app=1', icon: '/img/layout/appIcons/.png' }
]

Comment: hey, I couldn't find the `const dosomenthing` variable that your error said, is it in the code?

Comment: no sorry, I deleted it. I should have put it.

Comment: edit your question with dosomenthing const. without it it is impossible detect the problem

Comment: It's possible because other user resolved my question. The key is read the question and the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't define your function properly. It should be like this:

```
const doSomething = () => {
    console.log("hi");
}
```

Then, you can simply pass it to the TouchableOpacity like this:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={doSomething}>
   ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Finally I defined my funcion  under the imports and works! Thanks!